# Why when doing fullscreen JFrames and the buttons are not centered?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When not in fullscreen menu is like this:

[image]

However when I fullscreen is not organized:

[image]

Can someone help me please?

I don't know how the swings controls are centered on forms.

Thanks.

---

CODE

Login Form

```
    String sql="select * from logins where username=? and password=?";

            try{

        pst=(PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTUser.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jPass.getText());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){

            String idTipoLogin = rs.getString("idTipoLogin"); 

            if (idTipoLogin.equals("Administrador")) {

                jTMainMenuAdmin ah = new jTMainMenuAdmin();
                ah.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
                ah.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

MAIN MENU FORM

```
public class jTMainMenuAdmin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conexao = null;
PreparedStatement pst= null;
ResultSet rs = null;



public jTMainMenuAdmin() throws SQLException {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    initComponents();
    setTitle();
    setIcon();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(jTMainMenuAdmin.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    conexao=(Connection) CriaConexao.getConexao();
}



public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                new jTMainMenuAdmin().setVisible(true);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could we see some code? What layout manager are you using? are you calling  revalidate()?

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE You don't need to manually call revalidate when resizing... But yeah, would be useful to actually see some layout code when figuring out a layout problem

Comment: Thanks all for reply. I edit my question with some code. I hope help you to undestand my doubt.

Comment: Which IDE you are using ? If it is Netbeans, you can set "resize" property of you components...or you can use gridlayout.

Comment: Thanks all to help. I could already solve my problem. I enclosed in Jpanel and then I space around component, and it works.

Comment: Are you perchance storing passwords in plaintext?

Comment: @KarolS Holy mother of... OK, I'll close this tab and try hard to believe that he is using a custom component that returns a salted and hashed value in `getText()`. Epic spot though.

Comment: @KarolS For now yes. I'm still learning java.

Comment: Don't remove code from a question.  It is vandalism.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the default `GroupLayout` that Netbeans uses. You can create what you habe on a `JPanel` form instead. Then for the frame class, change the layout the `GridBagLayout`, then just add the `JPanel` form to the frame.

You can drag and drop the panel easily when your done, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435)

All you need to do to change the layout manager of the frame is look select and right click the frame in the Navigator window and select Set Layout. Just change it to GridBagLayout, then add the panel.

---

An aside: If you are just a beginner, I strongly suggest you learn to hand code first before you start messing with the IDE tools. The tool is pretty complicated if you don't first understand the basic. You can see go to [The Official Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Layout managers is a good place to start. Then move on to components/event listeners

---

Answer (score -1):

I think that you add the components with absolute positions and size as:

```
mybutton.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

If you want that you components adjust to the abailable space, you must use layouts.